# JS function not visible in onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Using ASP.NET + BootStrap 3 and trying to create tabs. Everything works fine except that I want that fine border to appear around the currently active tab. For this purpose I need to apply `active` class on that `li` (and remove `active` from other `li` elements). I'm trying to achieve that through the following simple JS function. But when I click a tab header, it tells me that the function `activateTab()` is not defined. Any clues?

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function activateTab(tab) {
            $("#ItemTabs ul li").removeClass("active");
            $(tab).addClass("active");
        }
     </script>

    <div id="ItemTabs">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li><a href="#tab-Details" onclick="activateTab(this.parentElement);">Details</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab-AdditionalInfo" onclick="activateTab(this.parentElement);">Additional Info</a></li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </div>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

N.B: I'm not a seasoned web developer and may be reinventing the wheel here. Plz let me know if there is an easier way.

Comment: Move your script to head. There is no need to place close to div.

Comment: @Satpal: I had it there just for readability. Does it somehow cause this problem?

Comment: @Satpal: That actually did the trick. Still want to see an explanation of why it doesn't work when put close to the `div`.

Comment: Can't answer your question why the placement makes so much diffrence, but the following code also works, no matter placed where:
activateTab = function(tab) {
            $("#ItemTabs ul li").removeClass("active");
            console.log(tab);
            $(tab).addClass("active");
        }

Comment: This is the key: `<EditItemTemplate>`.  The stuff inside the template, as is, is never written out the browser.  Rather, that template is read taken in, transformed and filled out, THEN written to the browser.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher: This was what I thought at first, but checking out my page in the browser showed that the function is actually included in the output. Else why would `div`, `ul` and `li` make their way out to the output?

Comment: Because the template was read in and processed and written out.  That's what templates do.  Think of a template like a Class -- a class is just a construct.  It isn't useful until you make an instance of it, and you can have multiple instances of the same class.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher: Yeah, but functions in my class are accessible from within each instance.

Answer (score 0):

when javascript file is having some compile error , that time it gives these kind of problem. 
You can try with this :

```
from $("#ItemTabs ul li").removeClass("active") TO this 
      $('div#ItemTabs > ul li').removeClass('active')
```